# Bootstrap Navbar not rendering on Heroku (Meteor)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, heroku

I am running a Meteor app on Heroku with a bootstrap Navbar. My local version runs fine however when I deploy to Heroku the Navbar doesn't render. Some people experiencing similar issues in Rails had to precompile the assets in order to solve this problem.

Has anyone come across a similar issue using Heroku/Meteor and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Meteor issue, some helper functions were buggy. It was not a heroku / bootstrap issue.